# Expected number of swaps required to get a palindrome out of a given string

Tags: probability, problem-solving, expected-value, palindrome

> Given a string, you keep swapping any two characters in the string randomly till the string becomes a palindrome. What is the expected number of swaps you will make? There will always be at least one palindrome which can be formed with the letters of the given string.
>   The length of the string will be at most 8 characters.
>   The string will consist of only lower-case letters ‘a’-‘z’.

How do I calculate this Expected value?

Comment: How is the input string generated? E.g. as a random string over some (which?) alphabet of given length $n$, restricted by the property that at most one letter occurs in odd multiplicity?

Comment: check this info above

Comment: For length $1$ or $2$, the anser is zero. For length $3$ it is $\frac{25}{26}\cdot 4+\frac1{26}\cdot 0$. Interestingly, the answer for length $4$ is the same. Computations for longer cases can be done using Markov processes, bu tbecome more and more tedious... (Edit: I think the computation for length $\ge3$ is wrong; it depends on the random process generating the initial string; replace $\frac{25}{26}$ with $\frac{3\cdot 25}{1+3\cdot 25}$.

Answer (score 5):

For any particular string, a Markov chain analysis can be done.  But it will be complicated.  I would be very surprised if there is a simple general formula.

EDIT: For example, consider the case $n=8$ with four distinct letters $abcd$, each occurring twice. Taking into account symmetries (permutations of the letters, and permutations of $1\ldots8$ that preserve the pairings $(1,8), (2,7), (3,6), (4,5)$, there are five states: 
$$ \eqalign{[a, b, c, d, a, b, c, d]\cr [a, b, c, d, a, b, d, c]\cr [a, b, c, d, a, c, b, d]\cr [a, b, c, d, a, c, d, b]\cr [a, b, c, d, d, c, b, a]\cr}$$
of which the last is a palindrome.
I get a transition matrix of
$$ P = \pmatrix{2/7 & 4/7 & 1/7 & 0 &0 \cr 1/7 & 4/7 & 0 & 2/7 & 0\cr
1/7 & 0 & 3/14 & 4/7 & 1/14 \cr 0 & 3/7 & 3/14 & 5/14 &0\cr 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\cr}$$
For example, the entry $P_{13} = 1/7 = 4/28$ because from state $1$, four of the $28$ possible transpositions go to state $3$: $(1,4)$, $(2,3)$, $(5,8)$, $(6,7)$. Thus $(1,4)$ takes $(a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d)$ to $(d,b,c,a,a,b,c,d)$, which
becomes $(b,d,a,c,b,a,d,c]$ by interchanging positions $1$ with $2$, $3$ with $4$, $5$ with $6$, $7$ with $8$, and then $(a,b,c,d,a,c,b,d)$ by permuting the letters ($a \to c \to d \to b \to a$).

Writing $P$ in block-matrix form as $\pmatrix{A & B\cr 0 & 1\cr}$ where $A$ is the top left $4 \times 4$ block, the expected numbers of steps until absorption in state $5$, starting in each of the first four states, form the column vector 
$$ u = (I - A)^{-1}\pmatrix{1\cr 1\cr 1\cr 1\cr} = \pmatrix{5201/39 \cr 1750/13 \cr 364/3 \cr 5138/39\cr}$$